# How to use sed to remove last double quote from each line of a file

Tags: sed

I am trying to remove the LAST double-quote from every line of a file.  I am very new to sed, and I think sed can easily do this, but cannot figure out the proper syntax.  Can anyone assist?
THanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the second strange downvote I've seen to a reasonable question from a new user in the last hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)"/\1/'
aaa"bbb              <-- Input
aaabbb               <-- Output
aaa"bbb"ccc          <-- Input
aaa"bbbccc           <-- Output
```

Comment: Thanks very much! This works great!  I was very close, but not close enough to work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

i guess you want to delete only the last occurrence of double quote in each line:

see the test:

```
kent$  cat t.txt
asdf"o"
asdfasdfsadf   ix"    "    000
"as;ldkfj;laskfj;lkasjdf;ljks

kent$  sed -r 's/"([^"]*$)/\1/' t.txt
asdf"o
asdfasdfsadf   ix"        000
as;ldkfj;laskfj;lkasjdf;ljks
```